# Graph is not interacting with the callback - Dash Python

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

the callback is not working in the dashboard application. The chart is plotted with no data on the dashboard.

However, when I plot the 'return fatPrevLinhas' as 'return fatPrevLinhas.show()' the graph returns with the data, but in another tab

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import random
import numpy as np
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output



#Create a dataframe 
start_date_str = '2023-04-01'
end_date_str = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
datas = pd.date_range(start=start_date_str, end=end_date_str, freq='D').to_list()
fatData = pd.DataFrame(index=datas)
fatData['Departamento'] = random.choices(departamentos, k=len(fatData))
fatData['Categoria'] = random.choices(categorias, k=len(fatData))
fatData['Produto'] = random.choices(produtos, k=len(fatData))
fatData['Faturamento'] = np.random.randint(500000, 900000, size=len(datas))
fatData['Previsão'] = np.random.randint(600000, 800000, size=len(datas))
fatData = fatData.reset_index()
fatData = fatData.rename(columns={'index': 'Data'})



#Create a filter
filter1 = dbc.Col([
    html.Label('Departamento', className='title_filter'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id="filtroDepartamento",
        className="filtro",
        options=[{'label':'Todos', 'value': 'Todos'},
                {'label':'Acessórios', 'value': 'Acessórios'},
                {'label':'Colchões', 'value': 'Colchões'},
                {'label':'Enxoval', 'value': 'Enxoval'},
                {'label':'Móveis', 'value': 'Móveis'},
                {'label':'Puericultura Leve', 'value': 'Puericultura Leve'},
                {'label':'Puericultura Pesada', 'value': 'Puericultura Pesada'}],
        value="Todos",
        multi=True
    )
], className='filter text-center')



#Callback
@app.callback(
    Output('fatPrevLinhas', 'figure'),
    Input('filtroDepartamento', 'value')
)
def update_my_graph(departamento):
    if len(departamento) > 0:
        print(f"Departamento selecionado: {departamento}")
        print(type(departamento))
        if 'Todos' in departamento:
            dff = fatData
        else:
            dff = fatData[fatData["Departamento"].isin(departamento)]
        fatPrevLinhas = go.Figure()
        fatPrevLinhas.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dff['Data'], y=dff['Previsão'], mode='lines', name='Previsão', line=dict(color='gray', width=2, dash='dash')))
        fatPrevLinhas.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dff['Data'], y=dff['Faturamento'], mode='lines', name='Faturamento', line=dict(color='blue', width=2)))
        fatPrevLinhas.update_layout(
            title_text='Faturamento vs Previsão',
            xaxis_title='Data',
            yaxis_title='Faturamento (R$)'
        )
        return fatPrevLinhas
    elif len(departamento) == 0:
        raise dash.exceptions.PreventUpdate
```

I tried plotting a chart with billing and billing forecast being filtered by department. I expected the graph interacting with the department filter, but the data disappeared from the graph